# ASP.NET MVC - check authentification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor

It is possible something like this in MVC, Razor?

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
       <span>Welcome&nbsp;</span> <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
        @Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Out", "Login")
}
else
{
       if (!@Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("login"))
       {
          return View("Login");
         
       }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it depends on what membership provider you are using?

Comment: You should not use Response.Redirect with MVC.  You're doing the wrong thing anyways.  You should be using an `[Authorize]` attribute on the action method, which will redirect to the login page if the user is not authenticated

Comment: Hy Erik! And thanks for your suggestion.  It's the first time when I heard about this attribute. I did a little research about Authorize so I've come the the conclusion that I should put this attribute before each action method from my project. It is correct? And why we shouldn't use Response.Redirect in MVC projects?

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@POIR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310408/poir)'s question post.

> Ok! I found out the answer:
>
> ```
>  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
>  {
>        <span>Welcome&nbsp;</span> <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
>         @Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Out", "Login")
>  }
>  else
>  {
>       if (!@Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("login"))
>       {
>
>          Response.Redirect("login");
>     
>        }
>  }
> ```